# Conditional Mean and Variance Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, norm

Let’s say I am attempting to gain insight on an archer’s ability to hit a target with varying distance from the target. I have data on the horizontal offset from the center of the target of attempts from the archer with distances varying continuously from the target from 10 feet to 50 feet. Let’s assume that the distribution of the offset from the bullseye is normal.

When shooting from 10 feet, the variance of the offset from the center of the target will be smaller than when shooting from 50 feet.

E[variance | distance = 10] < E[variance | distance = 50]

However the variance from distance = 10.1 will be very similar to the variance for when the distance = 10.

My ultimate goal is to have a normal distribution where the parameters (mean and variance) can vary with distance.

How would one put this together? Could I use linear models to predict the mean and variance at each distance and then gain a distribution for a given distance using the prediction?

Is there a way to use a bivariate distribution possibly? My concerns with this method is the fact that the distance isn’t a random variable but a control variable.

Let me know if there are any ideas on what would be best. Additionally if there are any specific packages in R or Python that you would recommend for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is inherently a 2D response variable. Robin Hood could miss because of an error in the vertical direction, the horizontal direction, or a combination of the two.

Comment: Yes that is true... this is just an example. The data I have only had horizontal offset. I would maybe expand to that with more data but my current concern matching distance to variance/mean (although mean will likely stay at 0)

Comment: Then I would model the miss distance—missing eight is positive, missing left is negative—as a function of the target distance. Plot a graph to visualize what’s going on.